# What does this sentence mean "lockdown isn’t an end unto itself. It's simply a means to an end."

Tags: phrase-meaning

If you need context for this sentence Refer to the Article from which this has been taken :
https://finshots.in/archive/business-uncertainty-and-the-ellsberg-paradox/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this capture's what you were confused about regarding this sentence but I would interpret this as meaning "our goal is not to have a lockdown; we just need to have a lockdown because it achieves something more important"